# How to customize general error messages of numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I am writing a `Vector` and `Matrix` classes that use `numpy` in the backend in order to abstract some common methods and calculations (specifically, physics calculations, but it's irrelevant). I would like to intercept common errors that may occur with the usage of these classes in order to write more readable error messages and hide the usage of `numpy`.

For example, assume we have `v = Vector([1, 2, 3])` defined. this code:

```py
v["a"] = 5
```

generates the error:

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

I would like something like:

> TypeError: Vector can be indexed by `int` or `slice` (`:`), not `str`.

I am not sure why `numpy` raises `IndexError` here instead of `TypeError` but whatever.
Another example is this code `v[6] = 0` which generates:

> IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3

I would prefer something like:

> IndexError: index 6 is invalid for 3 dimensional vector

Another example: `v[:2] = (4, 7, 12)` which generates:

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,) into shape (2,)

I'd prefer something like:

> ValueError: Can't set 2d slice of vector with 3d data

There are probably more examples I didn't come up with yet, but I think this illustrates the point. I want to customize the error messages for these different operations and I can't figure out how.

I can catch the exceptions and raise new ones with proper messages, but the exception doesn't contain information about why it was raised. Was it because of a wrong type, out-of-bounds index, or wrong dimensions?

There is no error code or something like that. The best option I came up with is parsing the error messages to understand what happened, but this feels like cheating, a hard work, and it relies on numpy not changing the format of the error messages. Is there a more reliable and clean way to do so?

Comment: You have identified the info provided - the exception class and the message.  That's all.  It may be better to test function arguments for dimensions, shape and dtype before numpy raises the error, rather trying to rewrite the message.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I think you missed the point. I am writing classes that represent vectors and matrices in physics, so from my perspective, the dimension of a vector is its length. I am trying to abstract the usage of numpy. consumers of this library shouldn't be aware that I use numpy behind the scenes and they should get error messages that describe the situation in a way they can understand.

Comment: @ShaiAvr Indeed I did not carefully read your question, sorry about that. My two cents: the only way I can think of this to work is to just wrap a lot of stuff inside `try: ... except: ...` blocks and then inspect the exceptions and raise your own. There isn't really a better way to do it except modifying `numpy` code itself, but I doubt you would want to do that. A better way to handle this would be to make sure user arguments make sense *before* using them so that you can raise your own exceptions before any `numpy` operation and be sure that the operation is safe if the checks pass.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to access the stack trace by,

> but the exception doesn't contain information about why it was raised.

you can use `print(traceback.format_exc())` under the `catch` statement. Also you'll have to import `import traceback`.

Comment: Not exactly. I want to know why the exception was raised in order to print a more suitable error message. For example, numpy raises `ValueError` for many different mistakes, and the only way to distinguish them is to look at the error message.